# Enable mask in a textfiend with sencha touch 2 forms?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

Is it possible to set a mask on a textfield in ST2 ?

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'phonenumber',
    label: 'Your phone number',
    mask: '(999) 999-9999'
},
```

Works in Ext but not in ST, I 'thought' ST was built on top of Ext

Comment: What do you mean by mask ? Any kind of validation ?

Comment: I mean like in ext the empty fields looks like "(999) 999-999" and as the user fills up the field it goes right into place. Not spkeaing of validation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no direct property in Sencha Touch that will do this job.

So, you may need to do something like this ..

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'phonenumber',
    label: 'Your phone number',
    placeHolder: '(999) 999-9999',
    listeners : {
      keyup : function( ) {
        // Code that checks the i/p value according to placeHolder goes here ...
      } 
    }
},
```

Btw, there's one [**post**](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?190303-Mask-or-format-TextField) on Sencha Touch forum.

Hope that helps you!

Comment: That should do it ! Thank you very much !

Comment: I feel that you're on fire today; check my other question out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334893/what-is-the-proper-way-to-load-an-external-javascript-in-sencha-touch-2