# javascript date time_ t conversion

Tags: javascript, date, format, time-t

I'm having a problem with the date format in javascript.
I'm getting a date in seconds (in time_t format) from a database (ex. 1364565600)
Now I want to convert this date to day, month, day (ex. Tuesday, March, 18th).

I hope this is possible.

```
 timestart: function (time_start) {
                ///////////////////////////////
                //////code for conversion//////
                return  time_start;
             }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you getting time in ticks from database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to convert seconds into date and time format in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262333/how-to-convert-seconds-into-date-and-time-format-in-java)

Comment: @Barmar how is this a duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

Multiply the seconds you're getting by 1000 and use a new Date() object, which takes milliseconds as a parameter (which is based on the same idea as time_t, which is seconds since epoch, but Date() is based on milliseconds):

```
 timestart: function (time_start) {

            return new Date(1000 * time_start);
         }
```

To get the Date string from it, use .toDateString(). There are a few other methods you could use to grab the date information and convert it to the types you want, you can find them here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Oops, forgot the 'new' operator, there it is now.

Comment: I know Date gives back miliseconds, but what I'm doing now is creating a time in miliseconds, I want a date in Tuesday, March, 18th. How do I put the miliseconds one into that format? Thanks for the fast reply

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8262333/how-to-convert-seconds-into-date-and-time-format-in-java here you will find what you looking for.

Comment: James, that's for Java, not JavaScript. I updated my post to tell the original poster the way to get the date string.

Comment: I can't get it to work, I'm kinda new to javascript. This is what I have.  
timestart: function (time_start) {
    var d = new Date(time_start).toDateString(); 
    return  d;
             }
         })
Sorry for the noobness, I'm learning.

Answer (score 0):

For verbose date manipulation in JavaScript, it's easiest to use a library if your deployment/optimization requirements permit. I've found [Moment JS](http://momentjs.com/) to be a good solution.

Comment: I'm working with sencha touch 2.1 I don't know if it is possible. Is it possible to format the date to 2013/03/18 starting from milisec?
Thanks for the reply

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334893/what-is-the-proper-way-to-load-an-external-javascript-in-sencha-touch-2) seems to be what you're looking for if you want to use an external library with Sencha Touch. If you just need the date to be readable (rather than a specific format), I suggest you go with @Rob G's answer and use `.toDateString()`

Comment: Usually there is only a requirement for one or two date formats, it's pretty easy to write a formatting function that suit.

Answer (score 0):

The [time value](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1) in a javascript date object is milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z (note UTC). As Rob G said, you can pass that value to the Date constructor to get a date object, then use Date methods to get what you want.

If you have a UTC time value in seconds from the same epoch, multiply it by 1,000 to get milliseconds and pass to the date constructor:

```
var date = new Date(timeValue);
```

You can now get either local or UTC date and time strings from the object using methods like [toString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.2), [toLocaleString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.5), [toISOString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.43) and so on. You can also use standard Date methods to get local time and date values, or UTC methods (e.g. [getUTCFullYear](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.11)) to get UTC values, to build a string of your own format.