# Convert UNIX to readable date in javascript

Tags: javascript, unix

I am trying to figure out, how i can convert a unix timestamp to a readable date using javascript.

For an example, i want to convert this unix: 1422360000, to a date format like this (or something simular):

```
 Tue, 27 Jan 2015 12:00:00 GMT
```

**Solution:**

```
 var timestamp = 1422360000;                 
 var date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript date time\_ t conversion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674093/javascript-date-time-t-conversion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the exact solution to the question.

```
var timestamp = 1422360000;                 
var date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
```

Result: Tue Jan 27 2015 13:00:00 GMT+0100

Answer (score 1):

Simply use [`Date(value)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

> value: Integer value representing the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC (Unix Epoch).

*Code*

```
new Date(1422360000)
```

Comment: Using your solution, i get something like this: "1970-01-17T11:06:00.000Z"

Comment: @Englund0110, that's correct even I am getting said time.

Comment: It has to be Date(value*1000)

Answer (score 1):

try this:

`new Date(1422360000).toString()`

That will make your date look like the string you want.