# c# datetime to javascript date with new date or dataparse

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have an ajax method where i request for a C# object that contains a DateTime. My javascript-console shows that i get the date in the following format:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: getDateTestUrl,
   dataType: "json",,
   success: function (response) {
      console.log(response.datetest);
   }
});
```

Result:

```
/Date(1454513400000)/
```

How do I make this into a javascript date? I tried to use both `New Date()` and `Date.parse()`

Example form the javascript-console:

```
Date.parse('/Date(1454513400000)/');
NaN

new Date('/Date(1454513400000)/')
Invalid Date
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format a Microsoft JSON date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/format-a-microsoft-json-date)

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/format-a-microsoft-json-date). You can also configure your C# backend to return dates in better format. Implementation really depends on technology.

Comment: @AleksandrIvanov—actually, a time value is probably the best format, since parsing strings is very problematic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [*Convert UNIX to readable date in javascript*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150469/convert-unix-to-readable-date-in-javascript).

Answer (score 4):

If the result is a string that is milliseconds since the ECMAScript epoch (same as UNIX, 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z), you can just grab the digits, convert to number and pass to the Date constructor:

```js
var s = '/Date(1454513400000)/';
document.write(new Date(+(s.replace(/\D/g,''))))
```

you can use: