# How to use Google Endpoints with Sencha Touch?

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, sencha-touch-2, google-cloud-endpoints

I've developed a prototype to my back end with Google Cloud Endpoints. I'm struggling now to find a way to create my client side, once it is developed on Sencha Touch.
I don't have deep knowledges on Sencha, but the team that is working on this side said that is not possible to have native code. So, our client side must be developed with JavaScript.
The js client works perfectly in an appengine application, for example, but I'm not having progress with Sencha.
Does anybody have an idea how can I handle it? Any suggestion or better way?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I have done:

- Added the required JS files (As user1258245 pointed out, the key is to include the JS files (Client JS and Base JS in my case)) to the project
  folder
- Linked them in my index.html
- Added a method to initialize my API calls on OnLaunch() function. So,
  it gets initialized when the app loads/launches.
- Just to make sure the response is received, I created a button with a method that shows the response. Inside the method, I had to call an 'execute' method with a parameter to fetch the response from the backend.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using the callback method as described here  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/consume_js

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=init">
</script>
```

Just include the google api js that you use for the backend in your Sencha Touch project.

There is a recommended way to use external js here:  [What is the proper way to load an external javascript in Sencha Touch 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334893/what-is-the-proper-way-to-load-an-external-javascript-in-sencha-touch-2)

If you can't get the init function to work, or it turns out you need it loaded right away, I guess you could just put it in index.html but it's warned against doing that for loading time reasons.

Comment: I tried to add it just in a plain html file and it didn't work, it was not recognizing the "gapi". I'll do it on Sencha and give a feedback.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly,your question is 'How to use google MAPS API with Sencha Application". Currently your application is not recognizing the google apps API.

I made the following changes in the application files.

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

**app.js**

// set the namespace as below and add the google libs under touch/src/lib/plugin

```
Ext.Loader.setPath({
    'Ext' : 'touch/src',
    'WU' : 'app',
    'Ext.plugin': 'lib/plugin'
});
```

// Add the required classes in the requires config

requires : [ 'Ext.MessageBox','Ext.plugin.google.Traffic','Ext.plugin.google.Tracker'],

launch : function() {

```
    //Tracking Marker Image
   var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        'resources/images/point.png',
        new google.maps.Size(32, 31),
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        new google.maps.Point(16, 31)
    );

  var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
        'resources/images/shadow.png',
        new google.maps.Size(64, 52),
        new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        new google.maps.Point(-5, 42)
    );
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, thank you but it's not really MAPS, I'm creating a backend with the appengine+endpoint! Anyways, I'll check how MAPS works there.