# Is SOAP Proxy available in Sencha Touch?

Tags: soap, sencha-touch

I'm aware that Sencha complete package includes Enterprise Data Connectors, in particular SOAP Data Connector.
However the SOAP Data Connector only seems to be available in EXTJS and not in Sencha Touch. Am I correct?
This is important to me because I'm evaluating about purchasing the package, but only if the SOAP Connector is available for Sencha Touch.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can include external javascript libraries, just add them into your app.json file described here. [What is the proper way to load an external javascript in Sencha Touch 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10334893/what-is-the-proper-way-to-load-an-external-javascript-in-sencha-touch-2). You can then access the library. The soap libary I've had the best luck with is http://javascriptsoapclient.codeplex.com/